# multi dimensional sorting in python

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, ordereddictionary

I am new to python, need an help to sort below multi-dimensional dictionary by field - "rank"

```
from operator import *
from collections import OrderedDict
print 'Dictionaries:'
l = {"test":{"rank":61,"test":2},"test1":{"rank":12,"test":2},"test2":{"rank":23,"test":2}}
```

I have tried with below approach,

```
d_sorted_by_value = OrderedDict(sorted(l.items(), key=attrgetter('rank')))
```

but getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to apply `lambda` to dict items, which is a tuple key/value. the value is the dict where you want to fetch `"rank"`, so the sort key can be written as:

```
lambda d:d[1]["rank"]
```

(`d[1]` gives you the dict stored as then value and `['rank']` accesses the value-dict data). Confusion comes from the various degrees of dicts in the input data.

testing:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = {"test":{"rank":61,"test":2},"test1":{"rank":12,"test":2},"test2":{"rank":23,"test":2}}

d_sorted_by_value = OrderedDict(sorted(l.items(), key=lambda d:d[1]["rank"]))

print(d_sorted_by_value)
```

returns:

```
OrderedDict([('test1', {'rank': 12, 'test': 2}), ('test2', {'rank': 23, 'test':2}), ('test', {'rank': 61, 'test': 2})])
```